# how can I close neokree's material navigation drawer at first?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

please help me!

I use neokree's MaterialNavigationDrawer.
https://github.com/neokree/MaterialNavigationDrawer

always Navigation drawer is open when I start application.

how can I close navigation drawer when start?

please help me.

Comment: sorry, just do to read wiki.

this.disableLearningPattern();

add in init() Method.

Answer (score 0):

Add below line in init() method.
this.disableLearningPattern();

Comment: sorry, i dont have 15 reputation;)